# css background tag not working

Tags: html, css

I am using the background tag in css to add an image to the body tag in my html file not nothing is apearing, i have look at all the answers here, and have followed them but to no avail. here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>Ironton Firedepartment Zombie 5k Run</title>
</head>

<body>

    </body>
</html>
```

here is my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

/*My css stuff*/

body{
background:url(images/zombie 5k TM AP stripped.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: That isn't a valid URL

Comment: Better not use white spaces in file names for the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below:

```
background:url('images/zombie 5k TM AP stripped.png');
```

Also ensure the image path is correct relative to the calling page.

Comment: ok that worked to a point now i only have half the pic, how do i fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another tip. I'd also replace the spaces in the file name with a dash `-` or an underscore `_` spaces. As spaces are url encoded as `%20`.

```
  zombie 5k TM AP stripped.png
```

to

```
  zombie-5k-TM-AP-stripped.png
```

Comment: why is there no scroll bars?

Comment: There's no scrollbars because there is nothing on the page. (inside the body)